# Some Grownwall type inequality for stochastic integral equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $B_t$ is a one dimensional Brownian motion. If I know that $X_t$ is positive and
$$ X_t \geq x + \int^t_0 b X_s ds + \int^t_0 \sigma X_s d B_s,$$
can I obtain that
$$ X_t \geq x \exp\left( (b-\sigma^2/2)t +\sigma B_t \right) ?$$